# error "line 1 column 27: invalid expression, unexpected input" in z3

Tags: z3

```
(simplify (str.++ (str.at "abc" 1) (str.at "abc" 0)))
(simplify (str.indexof "abcabc" "a"))
(simplify (str.indexof "abcabc" "a" 1))
(simplify (str.substr "xxabcyy" 2 3))
```

[link](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/sequences)

When I run the above code in `z3-smt` lib with file name as extension .smt or .smt2  using command:     `z3 -smt2 eg1.smt or z3 -smt2 eg1.smt2`

I get the error :

> (error "line 1 column 27: invalid expression, unexpected input")
>       (error "line 2 column 23: invalid expression, unexpected input")
>       (error "line 3 column 23: invalid expression, unexpected input")
>       (error "line 4 column 22: invalid expression, unexpected input")

Please help.

Comment: I don't have this problem. Which version do you use?

Comment: Strings support is relatively new so versions of Z3 prior to 4.5 will not be able to understand what they are. 
Use "z3 --version" to retrieve the version number:
Z3 version 4.5.1 - 64 bit - build hashcode d95ac58bada89101bf2765f9631f9b982cc7a5aa